# ASP Net Parser Error

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, asp.net-2.0

Line 1:  <%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="Berechtigungen.aspx.vb" Inherits="Berechtigungen.Berechtigungen" %>

My ASPX Page: Berechtigungen.aspx & Berechtigungen.aspx.vb

The .aspx.vb file:

```
<Serializable()>
Public Class Berechtigungen
```

Why is my Inherit not working?

Comment: what error you are getting